# Is there a way to know which data set is available in the Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, data-explorer

Is there a metadata table or something which would indicate the effective date of the set and perhaps the date and time it was refreshed?

(Typically, we have this kind of thing in our ETL for data warehouses: load date, batch identifier, row counts, load status, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homepage contains that information

http://odata.stackexchange.com

Look in the "most recent" column

Answer (score 2):

As a quick hack:

```
 select max(creationdate) from posts
```