# SEDE official host name? And OpenId not seen as the same from second hostname

Tags: support, data-explorer

I noticed another hostname for SEDE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52282/is-there-a-way-to-know-which-data-set-is-available-in-the-data-explorer/52284#52284). Is this the official site?

I logged in and my OpenId was associated with a new user. Surely it should see my existing OpenId as the same user irrespective of the site name.

Also BTW has the logged on time-out been reduced on SEDE? I've caught myself doing anonymous queries when I didn't intend to.

*[Sorry for the multiple queries.]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness, https://data.stackexchange.com/ is now the official name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes http://odata.stackexchange.com will be the official name.

I have a rather annoying merge account problem, one of the issues is that I already have 3 accounts from 3 hosts. (staging / live and odata) The database structure allows for a single user to have multiple open ids, but I do not have a UI / back end built yet. The tricky thing with account merge, is that you kind of need to build account unmerge, cause at some point somebody will make a mistake.

With regards to the logged in issue, I noticed I am being kicked out after every deploy, I need to track down what happening with the session and cookies.

Comment: hmmm... cookies...