# In data explorer... is "Most Recent" the date it was synced with the live data?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I see on the [data explorer homepage](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) that "most recent" is July 18th, is that the last time the data was synched or the last time a query was added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It represents the last time the data was synced with the live data, as evidenced by [Jeff's response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52282/is-there-a-way-to-know-which-data-set-is-available-in-the-data-explorer/52284#52284) to someone asking for that information.