# The Data Explorer, "most recent" dates are grossly wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

The Data Explorer [claims that the most recent data is from Dec 7th thru 13th, for all sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

[image: Last SEDE update]

But, it was pointed out to me that [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2253/how-many-moderators-have-the-sportsmanship-badge) returns an invalid row (NullUserException earned the badge as of Nov. 15th).

So then I made [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2276/badges-obtained-by-nulluserexception) and it claims that NullUserException only has 107 badges, with the latest earned on Nov. 12th.

However, [NullUserException actually has 115 badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception?tab=activity&sort=badges) -- all of them earned well before this latest SEDE update!

So what went wrong with the SEDE data?  And, how can we make sure that it won't happen again?

---

### Update:

As Conrad Frix points out, **none** of the data in SO appears to be updated!

I verified this with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2295/lastest-data-dates-in-the-data-explorer).  Indeed, the query on [several](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/2295/lastest-data-dates-in-the-data-explorer)  [other](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/s/2295/lastest-data-dates-in-the-data-explorer)  [sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/s/2295/lastest-data-dates-in-the-data-explorer), shows that apparently no data in the SEDE is newer than Nov 13th.

The "most recent" date displays are <strike>lies</strike> "suboptimal"!

Comment: If you run `​SELECT max(date) ,
(SELECT max(creationdate) FROM posts),
(SELECT max(creationdate) FROM users)
FROM badges` everything comes up with `11/13/2011` which probably indicates that the Data.SE home Page is a liar
​

Comment: Good point, @ConradFrix.  I've updated the question.

Comment: Methinks "most recent" refers to the last time SEDE has been updated.

Comment: By the way, have you seen [elections.se](http://elections.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ:  Pretty sure that the displays are meant for when the **data** is updated. A couple of days ago, these displays were all "nov 13" (as was the latest data) and the [data is supposed to be updated monthly](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq).  Also, in some post (which I will try to dig up), it's claimed that these dates are for data.  Finally, [the SEDE *code* was apparently last updated on Dec. 8th](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/updates/list).

Comment: Yes, it's official.  [The "most recent" dates are for when the **data** was (allegedly) updated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52284/148310).

Comment: Thanks for catching this.  As pointed out, part of the system thinks it was updated in December, and the other part thinks it is still from November.  Looking into it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has been resolved - I'd appreciate any testing you can do to make sure this is working properly.

Comment: Thanks!  What was the issue and how will it not recur?

Comment: Well, it looks like the data has been updated for all the sites (spot checked over 20).  But, there are slight discrepancies.  EG, [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) claims that The cooking site's "most recent" data is Dec 13, but [it is actually Dec 14](http://data.stackexchange.com/cooking/s/2277/).

Comment: Do all of the datetime columns have indices?  As I build up the query, it slows down way more than it should when some relatively small tables are added in.  The "***Include Execution Plan***" option appears to be busted.

Comment: @BrockAdams I [refactored your query here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2294/refactored-the-sede-most-recent-displays-lie) so that it runs

Comment: @ConradFrix, Ah, I see you made up for the appalling lack of indices on the datetime columns by assuming that the last ID is also the latest timestamp.  The the ID columns *are* all indexed, so this performs well.  Good workaround. Thanks!